How can I have a smoother transition when clicking subpage link?
I am creating a navbar and I want to have smooth transitions between the former page and the new one. Is there a way to make the two links transition smooth?
when I click on the links to open the subpages, the website refreshes kind of brutally... I can see a white before the new subpage appears...I'm not sure if this makes sense.
Maybe there is a way on css to create a slow transition?
HTML below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <div class="menu_navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="website.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery_page.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="artist_page.html">The Artist</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact_page.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <div class="sub_menu_navbar_1">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="about-shop_page.html">The Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-events_page.html">Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>


No, there is no such thing as transitions between diffrent pages in css. If you want to, you can make a more complex solution with a javascript library (for example barba.js)

I think you can use CSS and JavaScript for this purpose like this:
You can add a smooth transition effect to your page transitions using CSS. By default clicking on a link reloads the page.You need to prevent this default behavior using JavaScript.

It's Impossible but to use a single page website e.g. YouTube.
This happenes because browser closes one html file and then runs another. that's why you see that empty screen.
In one page websites, page is not reloaded, instead the page content changes.
